# How to increase the HTTP header size in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I need to increase the HTTP header size which is currently 16384 inside my Next.js app but I can't use the following command `node --max-HTTP-header-size=24576 server.js`. Can someone more advanced give me a shoulder?

Comment: Are you using web servers? e.g: nginx, apache,..

Comment: I can't get access to answer that question. Because I am a front end developer, tho it's the first time they had asked me to update the header size and I did lots of reading but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: maybe this can help? https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#custom-config

Answer (score 2):

You can pass node options via the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable.

```sh
NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=24576' node server.js
```